# Wrapper class in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I want to create a wrapper class so that all queries should not be in controller. Currently select queries are placed in Controller. But I want to create another layer for abstraction.

I already created a viewmodel class. But wrapper class is something else.

How do I do that?

Comment: create a new class and move your database code to that.Access that from your controller

Comment: Take a look at the [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

Comment: Create separate "service" dll project from where you make all your query calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do any queries directly in my controllers.  I have a service layer which my controller would call, and each service layer would do a call to the repository to insert, update or delete data or bring back data.

The sample code below uses `ASP.NET MVC3` and `Entity Framework code first`.  Lets assume you want to bring back all the countries and use it for whatever reason in your controller/view:

My database context class:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

My country repository class:

```
public class CountryRepository : ICountryRepository
{
     DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

     public IEnumerable<Country> GetAll()
     {
          return db.Countries;
     }
}
```

My service layer that calls my repository:

```
public class CountryService : ICountryService
{
     private readonly ICountryRepository countryRepository;

     public CountryService(ICountryRepository countryRepository)
     {
          // Check for nulls on countryRepository

          this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Country> GetAll()
     {
          // Do whatever else needs to be done

          return countryRepository.GetAll();
     }
}
```

My controller that would call my service layer:

```
public class CountryController : Controller
{
     private readonly ICountryService countryService;

     public CountryController(ICountryService countryService)
     {
          // Check for nulls on countryService

          this.countryService = countryService;
     }

     public ActionResult List()
     {
          // Get all the countries
          IEnumerable<Country> countries = countryService.GetAll();

          // Do whatever you need to do

          return View();
     }
}
```

There are lots of info on the internet on how to get you data and display it, inserting, editing, etc.  A good place to start is at http://www.asp.net/mvc.  Work through their tutorials, it will do you good.  All the best.

Comment: Why do we need service layer here? can't we call Respository class directly from controller?

Comment: You can.  I normally go through a service layer because most of the time I have to perform some busy logic before I call the repository.